# 3 table SQL join with an OR

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 tables (SQL Server), I want to run all selects as a single query returning one result set that looks like the following: [Mem1, Mem2, MutualDate, Name, Path]. Here is what I have so far but the OR makes it a little tricky...

tbl_mutual (Mem1, Mem2, MutualDate)
tbl_members (MemberID, Name)
tbl_pics (MemberID, Path)

lets say the @MemID is 21 and passed in as a parameter to the command.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_mutual WHERE Mem1 = @MemID OR Mem2= @MemID

SELECT Name FROM tbl_members WHERE MemberID = @MemID

SELECT TOP 1 Path FROM tbl_pics WHERE MemberID = @MemID

ORDER BY tbl_mutual.MutualDate DESC
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can be done (e.g. with simple joins or subquery selects), but what do you want your result set to look like?

Comment: I don't see a question here. What's the question? Do you want to put those three selects together into one query?

Comment: Yes, I want to put the selects into one query and have the rsult set look like this - Mem1, Mem2, Name, Path

Comment: Much better if you include the sample data and your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple [tbl_pics] paths (if they exists) but same member id

```
SELECT 
    Mem1,
    Mem2, 
    MutualDate,
    Name,
    Path
FROM tbl_mutual
INNER JOIN tbl_members
    ON (Mem1 = @MemID
        OR Mem2 = @MemID)
    AND MemberID = @MemID
INNER JOIN tbl_pics
    ON tbl_members.MemberID = tbl_pics.MemberID
ORDER BY tbl_mutual.MutualDate DESC
```

For single [tbl_pics] path but same member id

```
SELECT 
    Mem1,
    Mem2, 
    MutualDate,
    Name,
    (SELECT TOP 1 path FROM @tbl_pics WHERE [@tbl_pics].MemberID = @MemID)
FROM tbl_mutual
INNER JOIN tbl_members
    ON (Mem1 = @MemID
        OR Mem2 = @MemID)
    AND MemberID = @MemID
ORDER BY tbl_mutual.MutualDate DESC
```

Comment: The bottom one is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you.  Only thing is the 'path' column is returned with no column name.  How can I apply a name to that column?  Thank you again.

Comment: Figured it out just need an this - ...@MemID) AS Path - thank you.